# items margin top issue

Tags: html, css, margins

I have 3 list items with `display: block`. I want the even element to be positioned a little lower but when I try with `margin-top` all my elements are lower positioned.

```css
.hero__description-right {
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.description__item {
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}

.description__item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.description__item:nth-child(2n) {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero__description-right">
  <li class="description__item">
    <h2><span class="hashtag">#</span> Text</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="description__item test">
    <h2><span class="hashtag">#</span> Text</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="description__item">
    <h2><span class="hashtag">#</span> Text</h2>
  </li>
</div>
```

How can I position only the even elements? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you only want to visually move the even elements - in that case it'd be better to use `transform: translate` instead of margins (this is because `margin` affects other elements in the document flow, whereas transform is only *visually* moving them), for example:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li:nth-child(even) {
  transform: translateY(5px);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Quick callout - I'm trying to remember the exact bug, but I recall there being an issue using `translateY`, and needing to use `translate(0,5px)` instead for full browser compatibility. That might have just been when animating, however, it was a while ago.

Comment: @jmcgriz Fair point, though I'm not familiar with said issue. If you find a reference feel free to edit!

Comment: as a side note : replace the transform with margin-top and add `vertical-align:top` then it will work ...

Answer (score -1):

When put in a proper snippet, it mostly works - if I understand your question. The biggest issue seems to be that, `li` elements do not belong inside a `div` - they need to be inside a `ul` or `ol` element.

```css
.hero__description-right {
 margin-left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.description__item {
 margin-top: 0px
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 clear: both;
}

.description__item:last-child {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.description__item:nth-child(2n) {
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="hero__description-right">
 <li class="description__item">
  <h2><span class="hashtag">#</span> Text</h2>
 </li>
 <li class="description__item test">
  <h2><span class="hashtag">#</span> Text</h2>
 </li>
 <li class="description__item">
  <h2><span class="hashtag">#</span> Text</h2>
 </li>
</ul>
```